# What is the generic name for a 'Yale lock'?

Tags: generic-term

*Yale*  is one of those brand names which has been around for ever.

[image]

But that type of lock (not the same as a mortice lock) must have a generic name.

Comment: What characteristics distinguish this kind of lock from other types?

Comment: @DanBron If you look at my link you will see. Is it sufficient to call it a *night latch*, or a *deadlock* ?

Comment: Your link shows numerous kinds of lock sold under the Yale brand, including mortise locks.

Comment: @WS2 I did (click your link). I didn't (see what distinguishes this kind of lock). Mind elaborating and describing what you mean sir let in the body of your question?

Comment: @DanBron Sorry. I have now put the specific one there. I guess it is called a 'latch lock'. The trouble is that 'Yale' is synonymous with this type of lock, so even though Yale make mortice locks, the latch lock is still called a *Yale lock*.

Comment: @Mari-Lou Thank you again for your helpfulness. I have not discovered how to do that.

Comment: OK :) See if I can explain how it's done. Click on the image you wish to post, open link in a new window. Copy its URL address. In the edit toolbox there is an icon of a picture (showing mountains and a sun), click, in the pop up message where it says: "You can also provide a link from the web." paste the original url (web address) and voila!

Comment: @Mari-LouA I will have a go. Thanks. But rugby world cup about to start!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Locks that set themselves when you pull or push the door closed are usually called *latches* (similar to cabinet latches). When the latch is separate from the door handle, especially if it is a surface mounted unit, it is usually called a *[night latch](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Prime-Line-Single-Cylinder-Brass-Painted-Locking-Night-Latch-U-9967/100158554)*.

> a door lock having a spring bolt operated from the outside by a key and from the inside by a knob *[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/night+latch)*

[image: night latch]

Locks that require the turning of a key or knob to set are usually called *[deadbolts](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Prime-Line-Single-Cylinder-Brass-Surface-Deadbolt-U-9956/100541785)*, whether they are surface mounted or part of a mortise lock.

> A bolt engaged by turning a knob or key, rather than by spring action. *[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/deadbolt)*

[image: deadbolt]

Surface mounted deadbolts that have locking bars that drop down are often called *[vertical deadbolts](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Prime-Line-Single-Cylinder-Painted-Brass-Jimmy-Resistant-Entry-Door-Deadlock-U-9970/100133642)* (also called *jimmy proof* or *jimmy resistant* lock or deadbolt).

[image: vert deadbolt]

Comment: I am sure you have given the right answer. But when I had to call a locksmith the other day to replace one, I found the easiest way of describing it was to call it a *Yale lock*.

Comment: @WS2 were you given a key with the lock?  Because these are not locks and are different than the picture you posted which shows a Yale deadbolt.

Comment: @WS2 http://www.yaleresidential.com/en/yale/yaleresidential-com/residential/ye-edge/deadbolts/

Comment: @michael_timofeev Yes the one installed, is as per the picture I posted. It had keys that open it from outside, but no key needed on the inside. Though you can turn the key anti-clockwise on the outside and secure the door so that it could not be opened from the inside. I don't know if there is a *deadbolt* involved. But since that door also has a mortice lock on it - there is perhaps no need.

Answer (score 6):

The lock that uses the familiar notched key inserted into a rotating cylinder is called a "cylinder lock", generally utilizing a "pin tumbler lock" mechanism internally.

The cylinder lock is quite ubiquitous, and is mainly distinguished from the old fashion "lever lock" scheme utilizing what many people may (somewhat erroneously) call a "skeleton key".  However, some cheap padlocks and the like utilize a scheme similar to the lever lock internally, even though the keys vaguely resemble cylinder lock keys.

The lock with a knob on one side that can lock you in for the night is a "deadbolt lock".  The deadbolt lock has a non-tapered "bolt" that is operated by some sort of toggle mechanism inside.

The lock with a knob (that you turn) on both sides is generally referred to as a "doorknob".  Note that one of the knobs may contain a cylinder lock to allow the unit to be locked/unlocked from the "outside", and some sort of button on the other side to permit locking from the "inside".

A lock with a tapered, spring-operated "bolt", to permit the lock to automatically "catch" when the door is shut, is generally referred to as a "latch" or "spring latch" (though "spring bolt" is another term that is sometimes used).  (Most doorknob assemblies incorporate a "latch".)

The Yale company manufactures most if not all of the above variations.

Comment: But the original *Yale* lock was the latch type, which, if the latch is down, automatically locks as the door closes. Your contribution is helpful, but I think the person who described it as a 'latch lock' has provided the answer I was seeking - unless you feel strongly to te contrary.

Comment: @WS2 - It was unclear what attribute of the lock you were focusing on.

Comment: We do use brand names differently, but in Britain when anyone says *Yale lock* I am pretty sure they mean a latch lock. Although nowadays of course many other manufacturers make those locks. What would be the short name for such a lock in your neck of the woods?

Comment: @WS2 - Probably just a "door latch", though, of course, that suffers from being non-specific.  (I associate "Yale" mostly with the deadbolt locks which had been retrofitted onto many doors when I first became aware of them ca 1955.  The Yale cylinder was bright shiny brass, while everything else on the door was corroded.)

Comment: This is, without a doubt, the right answer. Yale invented the pin tumbler lock and that is why that type of lock is often called a Yale lock. The latch has nothing at all to do with the lock. On my front door, I have a Yale lock with a deadbolt type latch. And I am in Britain.

Comment: I'd go with "cylinder lock", The OP asks for a word for _the lock_. Unfortunately, the original picture also shows the latch mechanism. This is separate from the lock, (as Olecksandr R comments), which is the "Yale" part. The other bits shown (like the "nightlatch") have confused the replies, I  think.

Answer (score 1):

They are called "pin tumbler" locks.

[image: pin tumbler lock]

The complete mechanism is called a deadbolt.

[image: deadbolt]

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yale_(company)), and its [linked companion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_tumbler_lock), a Yale lock is known generically as a *pin tumbler lock*:

> Yale is a lock manufacturer associated with the pin tumbler lock,
>   which is often known as the Yale lock.

Comment: But the one in the picture is not a 'latch lock' which locks automatically when the door closes. That is what in Britain has always been called a *Yale lock*. I do realise that nowadays Yale make all kinds of locks.

Comment: I agree with this.  WS2's question was specific.  The original post didn't have a picture which has two different kinds of locking mechanisms.  This changes it and makes it ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of **Cylinder Lock** - described by Wikipedia as

> a lock constructed with a cylinder that a locksmith can easily unscrew
>   to facilitate rekeying